# Multiple imports failing with compass

Tags: css, ruby, sass, compass-sass, compass

When I try to compile my compass project I get

> error sass/screen.scss (C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:346:in
>   `rmdir' : No such file or directory -
>   /.sass-cache/75fcaf1b4852ceb732871195e41567cc2a7d899
>   7/C%058/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/
>   _support.scssc20150210-7000-1v0fh8k.lock)

I've narrowed it down to the following. For some reason I can't do a general import:

```
//@import "compass/css3";
```

And I can't have multiple imports from the same package. I have to choose one or the other:

```
//@import "compass/css3/text-shadow";
@import "compass/css3/inline-block";
```

Comment: I've also run 'compass clean' and deleted '.sass-cache' to no avail

Comment: I think The problem is here 'C%058' It's trying to get to my ruby directory, but for some reason it's prepending the current directory.